# SDL_sndioaudio.c: undefined reference to `sio_*'

Tags: reference, header, undefined, openal

I'm facing a problem when compiling a c++ project with OpenAL and SDL2 dependencies on Debian stretch

```
libs/openal/libopenal.a(sndio.c.o): In function `sndio_stop_playback':
sndio.c:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `sio_stop'
libs/openal/libopenal.a(sndio.c.o): In function `sndio_start_playback':
sndio.c:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `sio_start'
sndio.c:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to `sio_stop'
libs/openal/libopenal.a(sndio.c.o): In function `sndio_proc':
sndio.c:(.text+0x278): undefined reference to `sio_write'
libs/openal/libopenal.a(sndio.c.o): In function `sndio_reset_playback':
sndio.c:(.text+0x312): undefined reference to `sio_initpar'
sndio.c:(.text+0x388): undefined reference to `sio_setpar'
sndio.c:(.text+0x3e7): undefined reference to `sio_getpar'
libs/openal/libopenal.a(sndio.c.o): In function `sndio_close_playback':
sndio.c:(.text+0x61e): undefined reference to `sio_close'
libs/openal/libopenal.a(sndio.c.o): In function `sndio_open_playback':
sndio.c:(.text+0x6af): undefined reference to `sio_open'
../libs/sdl2/build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_sndioaudio.o): In function `load_sndio_syms':
SDL_sndioaudio.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `sio_open'
SDL_sndioaudio.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `sio_close'
SDL_sndioaudio.c:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `sio_setpar'
SDL_sndioaudio.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `sio_getpar'
SDL_sndioaudio.c:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `sio_start'
SDL_sndioaudio.c:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `sio_stop'
SDL_sndioaudio.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `sio_read'
SDL_sndioaudio.c:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `sio_write'
SDL_sndioaudio.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `sio_initpar'
```

I currently have those packages installed

```
libglu1-mesa-dev
libalut0
libalut-dev
libsndio-dev
libroar-dev
libpulse-dev
portaudio19-dev
```

Any idea of what I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities to fix that

1. **Uninstall sndio package**

   `sudo apt remove libsndio-dev:*`
2. **Add sndio link flag**

   - **CMakeLists.txt**: add `sndio` in `target_link_libraries` so that it looks like
     `target_link_libraries(SDL2 sndio)`
   - **Makefile**: add `-lsndio`